# drupal : Getting real time status as in drupal7 testing module

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I have a question to those who are familiar with drupal7 testing module. When you test a module on drupal7 you will get real time status of the test process, How can I do this ?

Thank you guys

Comment: How can you do what? Please elaborate. Did you know Drupal is open source? You can read the code and see how it's been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for ways to debug drupal there are two modules that I would suggest.

1. the Devel module - http://drupal.org/project/devel

This module offers a number of differerent tools that make it very easy to debug drupal code, including a very easy to use function that allows you to output just about any variable or object anyplace in the code into a drupal status message. It also includes a huge host of other tools that make developing and theming drupal much easier. If you don't have it installed I highly recomend it, most experienced drupal developers would consider it indispensable.

1. Drupal for Firebug - http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug

This module allows you to use a similar debug function, but instead of outputting to the message it will output to firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You can test with either the built in simpletest module (first you must enable it) or with Drush; Drush also requires the testing module to be enabled.